# ListService in Abp.io with Syncfusion Grid sample

Tags: angular, .net-core, paging, syncfusion, abp

I want to use ListService of abp.io in angular project with Synfusion Grid. I want to achieve pagination through ListService.

Please give me code example of both Angular and Abp.io implementation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.